# Python MVC Implementation

Tags: python, model-view-controller, webapp2

Should I be using webapp2 to call the right controller by importing all the controllers, and then use `webapp2.Route()` to call the proper controller; or should I split the URL into segments such as `/< class >/< method >/< query array >`, and then make an other class call the proper class, and method based on the URL?

Comment: @msanford both methods use webapp2. Thus, changing the title was very unfitting.

Comment: Right, my bad. Overzealous editing. I wonder why it was approved...

Comment: I think it's a matter of preference, until the file with routing information grows too large.  Then it makes sense to break the routes into modules by class, as you describe.  Are you planning on making a huge project out of this?